# export current WLAN Profile using command line

Tags: networking, cmd, profile, wireless, wifi

I want to export the WLAN profile to an xml file , but I want to detect the current connected WLAN , now I have the following

```
netsh wlan export profile "profile-Name" folder="C:\"
```

in my case I need to know the WLAN profile name , is there any possible way to detect the current used profile automatically from the CMD or C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can get it using the command

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```